# Retrieve Data from Sharepoint List

Tags: list, jquery, soap

I'm trying to get Data from SP List via SOAP.

It works for standard columns like "ows_Modified". But if I try to get Data from Column I created (example: "DogNames") in the SP List by myself, it doesn't work.

Could you please take a look. It seems like I've to make some modifications

```
function getSharepointListData (rightList) {

   var listName = rightList;

var soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
             <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                <listName>"+listName+"</listName> \
                <viewFields> \
                    <ViewFields> \
                       <FieldRef Name='Author' /> \
                   </ViewFields> \
                </viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";

$.ajax({
    url: "http:URL/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: processResult,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});

function processResult(xData, status) {

var j = 0;
var myArray = new Array();

$(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {

    //var content = $(this).attr("ows_Modified");
     var content = $(this).attr("dogNames");


   myArray[j] = content;

    $("#tasksUL").append(content + '</br>');
   j++;

}); }}
```

Is it also possible somehow to count the columns in the list? For example to get information from Column 1, 2 ..... instead of the name.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you try `ows_dogNames`?

Comment: Version of SharePoint?

Comment: yes i tried with ows_dogNames. I get an Array with 12 "undefied" objects (12 rows in the list). Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Try including your custom field in the <ViewFields> section

Comment: Have you considered using SPServices? Works on SP 2010 and easier to work with. https://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: i will try it, If I will not get this work in the next near future:)

Comment: Please refer the below link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469859/retrieving-sharepoint-lists-using-soap

Comment: Please refer below link. May be this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469859/retrieving-sharepoint-lists-using-soap

Answer (score 1):

Put this in an html file somewhere on your site and replace the `SITE` and `listName` values. Let me know what you get back.

```
<html><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script>
SITE = "http://sharepointsite/";

$(document).ready( function(){
    $().SPServices({
        webURL: SITE,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "dogNames",
        async: false,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='dogNames' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            /***********************************Debugging******************************************************/
                var out = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
                node: xData.responseXML
                });
                $("#debug").html("").append("<b>This is the output from the GetList operation:</b>" + out);
            /***************************************************************************************************/
        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="debug"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it with SP Services. Thank you all for help!

```
var SITE = URL;
var myArray = new Array();
$(document).ready( function(){
    $().SPServices({
        webURL: SITE,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: "dogNamesList",
        async: false,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='dogNames' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

           $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 

                var data = ($(this).attr("ows_dogNames"));

                var j = 0;

                myArray[j] = data;

                j++;


            });

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Since you seem to have had a lot of help of the answers here, please at least upvote them :)